# Stack function remove end function in C

Tags: c, stack

Wanted to check with the community on whether this function to `get_end()` works properly.  A `typedef struct queue` has a head and a tail and is shown below.

The `stack` has a head and a tail and the head always points to the "front/bottom" of the `stack` while the tail keeps track of the "end/top" for removing the end.  The struct is a generic term and in this case is a structure of ints.

The `get_end()` is trickier than writing a `pop` and `push` function and wanted to check with the community on whether this function looks correct.

```
typedef struct node{
    int a, b;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct stack{
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
}Stack;


 Node* get_end(Stack* q){
    Node *right, *left, *temp;
    right = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    left = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(q->head == NULL && q->tail == NULL){
        temp = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    else if(q->head == q->tail){
        temp = q->tail;   
        q->head = q->tail = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    else{
        right = q->head;
        while(right->next != NULL){
            left = right;
            right = right->next;
        }
        left->next = NULL;
        q->tail = left;
        return right;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I will edit this

Comment: stack overflow is not a debugging or tutorial service. It is a Q&A site. Take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: I really wonder how one could write such code in the first place. Anyway, standard comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: @Olaf: What is the downside to casting the result of `malloc()`?

Comment: @JonathanWood: With 33k reps you should already know the answer. If not: see the info-page, there is a link.

Comment: "Wanted to check with the community on whether this function to get_end() works properly". That is not what Stackoverflow is for. That is what *testing* is for. You construct different test cases and run those against your code so that you can answer the "does it work" question yourself.

Comment: `right = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    left = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));` : You do not need. They are  memory leak.

Comment: @Olaf  - someone has to start somewhere...pretty harsh to someone who wants to learn C

Comment: @JJL: Sorry for being ambiguous (I'm not a native English speaker). I meant the first version of your code. You apparently know better, so I wondered why you posted the first version actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

First, you're calling `malloc` for two objects that you immediately abandon. So your code has a memory leak.

Second, you already have a pointer to the end of the linked list - it's called `tail`. So you can rewrite all three cases in terms of one comparison. There are three cases: head==tail==NULL, head==tail!=NULL, and head!=tail:

```
prev = NULL;
curr = q->head;
while (curr != q->tail) { /* h==0 skip, h==t skip, h!=t follow links */
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
}
if (prev) {               /* h==0 skip, h==t skip, h!=t unlink */
    prev->next = NULL;
}
q->tail = prev;           /* h==0 noop, h==t nullify, h!=t unlink */
if (q->head == curr) {    /* h==0 noop, h==t nullify, h!=t skip */
    q->head = prev;
}
return curr;
```